# Creating list of lists split by occurence in string

Tags: python, list

my task is to make a list of lists out of my big list and split those based on occurence of string in one elements of that big list.

This is start of my list and there will be occurence of 'dialog #' many times -
I would like to split that big list into lists so every one will starit with

'dialog #'

and then will have all strings below that until another occurence of 'dialog #' will appear, that will start building another list.

Then i would like to iterate trought all the lists created from that one big list.

I have some experience with Python but this is above my level...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: please post your input and expected output

Comment: ... and add some things you tried already yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
source_list = ['dialog #', 'a', 'b', 'dialog #', ... ]
new_list = []
begin = 0
local_list = []
for item in source_list:
    if item == 'dialog #':
        if begin == 0:
            local_list.append(item)
            begin = 1
        else:
            new_list.append(local_list)
            local_list = [item]
    else:
        local_list.append(item)
new_list.append(local_list)
```

I do not check it...

Answer (score 0):

```
def split_list(input_list, delimiter):

    result_list = []

    while len(input_list) > 0:

        elem = input_list.pop(0)

        if elem == delimiter:

            if 'sub_list' in locals():
                result_list.append(sub_list)

            sub_list = [elem]

        elif len(input_list) == 0:

            sub_list.append(elem)
            result_list.append(sub_list)

        else:

            sub_list.append(elem)

    return result_list
```

Test:

```
test_data = ['dialog #', 'foo', 'bar', 'dialog #', 'baz', 'zaz']

split_list(test_data, 'dialog #')
```

> [['dialog #', 'foo', 'bar'], ['dialog #', 'baz', 'zaz']]